# Apache hits max connections after server upgrade

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I recently upgraded a web server from Debian 8 to Debian 11, no errors concerning Apache were noted. Before the upgrade the website performed smoothly. The only configuration change made was to switch to php7.4 from php5.

Apache is set to use mpm-prefork with a MaxRequestWorkers, initially set to 150.
After the upgrade the max connections limit has been reached multiple times. The first few times I upped the MaxRequestWorkers to 200, then 256. I then analyzed the server hardware, not having set it up, and set the ServerLimit to 400 with a MaxRequestWorkers at 300. It is still hitting this limit. When it does I have to restart the Apache service, systemctl restart apache2. If I do not it will continue to be unresponsive until it is restarted.

I have pulled and analyzed the logs using GoAccess and have found no evidence of DOS attacks or bad clients. It feels as if the upgrade caused an issue somewhere. Looking for possible ideas as to why this may be.

Edit: Found a second possibly related issue where files that were accessible to download no longer complete the download. The download gets "stuck" after a percentage, 2%-40% in tests, of the file is downloaded. This leaves processes in a limbo state which is most likely causing the original issue noted. The files do test as good, via SHASUM comparison with the originals on other servers, and text files can be read directly on the web server via console.

Edit2: Over the months since asking this question the problem has continued. Analyzing the server status and log outputs shows two issues at work. First is a few DOS attacks, these are being looked at and handled above me.

The second is the file download issue already mentioned above. Larger files, over 4MB in tests, are not being downloaded with the transfer being stopped within a few seconds of starting. This is occurring no matter where the client is, on the LAN, via VPN, or via the Internet. Full log checks, with debug at trace8(!), show no output concerning the stoppage of the download. Server status shows the download process with a M status of W aka Sending Reply. The process never finishes and when enough of these are created the max process number is hit and the site basically goes offline.

Comment: I'd have a look at the PHP, the php-fpm configuration.  Does the PHP connect to a database?

Comment: I cannot find any php-fpm configuration files. PHP is used for database connections though that part of the site is currently down for unrelated reasons.

Comment: You're sure the hanging requests have no relation to "that part of the site"?  Check Apache's server-status page.  How is the PHP handled by Apache if you don't have php-fpm?

Comment: Said portion of the site is for Pydio 8. It was found to be inaccessible after the upgrade, php7.4 not supported, so was disabled. The problem remained afterwards.
php-fpm is not even installed, just the standard php binary along with the Apache mod.

Comment: Ah yes, "The PHP version reached end-of-life state on 31 December 2019", ie. two years ago.  So, is PHP still in use?  What does server-status show?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is as multiple pages have the php extension. Not certain what for though as I do not develop the site, just manage the server. The server-status makes no mention of PHP.

Comment: Perhaps you could concentrate on what server-status does mention?  First those requests with the longest wait.